# gradle project with aspectj 1.8

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, aspectj

I'm trying to add aspectj compilation to a gradle project.

[This](https://github.com/eveoh/aspectj-example/blob/master/build.gradle) is the only sample i could find, but it seems this plugin does not support aspectj 1.8 (for java 1.8)...

Did anyone configure aspectj compilation with gradle?